# how to calculate sum of similar elements in a 2d python list?

Tags: python

I have a 2d list like this

```
array = [['product_1',1500],['product_2',2500],['product_3',4500],['product 1',1000],['product 2',3000],['product 3',1200]]
```

what I need to get is the python 2d list ordered by the largest sum, like

```
#arr = [[product_3,5700],[product_2,5500],[product_1,2500]]
```

here is what I tried

```
arr = []
i=0
for item in array:
    if item[0] not in arr:
        item[0]=array[i][0]
        item[1]=array[i][1]
        arr.append(item)
        print('array[%d][0]'%i,array[i][0])
        print(arr)

    else:
        item[1]+=item[1]
        print('item[1]',item[1])
    i+=1
```

but this only appends all the elements to the list. How to find the sum of each element in the list and sort them?

Comment: How similar are we talking, here? Is the only possible difference the presence or absence of an underscore/space? Or do we need truly "fuzzy" logic, e.g. to notice that "product 1" and "prduct 1" should be in the same category?

Comment: This question implies a lot of changes in order to go from your actual code to your expected output. It would probably be better for you to try another route.

Comment: Why does the final list contain `product 1` and not  `product_1`? What are the rules here?

Comment: There are many tutorials and postings that deal with these topics.  I believe that your problem, once it's properly specified, will be neatly solved by `groupby` to gather the elements, and `sum` to find their sum.  Both of these are Python methods.  With those keywords, you should be able to search out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

array = [['product_1',1500],['product_2',2500],['product_3',4500],['product 1',1000],['product 2',3000],['product 3',1200]]
array = [[i.replace(' ', '_'), j] for i, j in array]

d = defaultdict(dict)

for x, y in array:
    d[x] += y

output = list(reversed(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])))
```

Output:

```
[('product_3', 5700), ('product_2', 5500), ('product_1', 2500)]
```